# Raffle thing not working

Tags: javascript

### Coding problem for raffle won't work!

```
var i = 0;
var count;
var names = [
    "Stefon",
    "Garret",
    "Brandon"
];

function GetRandomInt(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*i+1);
}

function CallWinner(){
    var ID = GetRandomInt();
    document.write("<hr>"+names[ID]+" has won with the ID of "+id+"!");
}

do {
    i++;
    for(count=0;i<=names.length;){
        count++;
        document.write(names[count]+" has been assigned to the raffle ID, "+count+"<br>");
    }
} while (i<=names.length);
```

For some reason this isn't working, it acts like an infinite loop or maybe it crashes the tab, it works but then it crashes the tab. Please help.

Comment: Index at `length` is wrong and a `for-loop` using `i` rather than `count` is also wrong!

Comment: Look very closely at `for(count=0;i<=names.length;)`. Your condition `i<=names.length` will always come true => infinite loop

Comment: I honestly don't understand what the logic behind those nested `while` and `for` loops is supposed to be and I have a suspicion neither do you. Your `for` loop increments `count` but uses `i` in the condition, which causes the infinite loop. Read up on loops again and rethink this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` is document.wrong. Please use something more modern and less prone to doing confusing things. This function tries to write to the current document. If the document has already been processed, the document will be replaced with a blank one with your argument. You don't want that; use the proper DOM methods instead.

Your `GetRandomInt` function is broken; it should return a random accessible index in the array, not a static number.

Try something like this instead:

```js
const names = [
  "Stefon",
  "Garret",
  "Brandon"
];

function GetRandomIndex() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
}

function CallWinner() {
  const index = GetRandomIndex();
  const hr = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  hr.textContent = names[index] + " has won with the ID of " + index + "!";
}
names.forEach((name, count) => {
  const div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  div.textContent = name + " has been assigned to the raffle ID, " + count;
});
CallWinner();
```